# Is this a good method to validate predictors?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have some time series data. The data changes continuously; Thus, the underlying, true distribution is not constant, but it does not change rapidly.

What I do is:

1. I find good performing predictors from the oldest data to 365 days ago and put them into set A.
2. Out of set A, I test which of those predictors have good performance for data from 365 days ago to today and put them into set B.
3. Out of set B, I test which predictors have the best performance for the entire data set. I then use that predictor to try to predict new incoming data. I do this on a rolling basis daily.

Is this a good method to validate predictors?

Is step 3 necessary? Considering step 2 already measures the predictability of the predictors. Should I just pick the best predictor resulting from step 2?

Comment: How are you measuring the performance of a predictor? And what goal are you optimizing for?

Comment: You could post this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ if you dont get a satisfying answer. When you postulate the data generating process changes over time the problem gets much more advanced. Do you need this assumption?

Comment: @Karl  Well I'm just trying get a good predictor for future data without overfitting the historical data. Hence step 2. Is that sufficient without step 3? Or is step 3 necessary to ensure the predictor is still relevant (time-wise) for the new data?

Comment: @confusedstudent  Oh they banned me from that exchange for posting too many stupid questions, haha.  Yes, the data generating process is changing over time. Thus, I can't use cross-validation to validate a predictor for this year's economic data with economic data from 1950s. Can only validate forwards.